# Shading issues with boolean

Tags: modifiers, shadows

Before you leave a comment, I know this is a common issue, but I have tried all of the solutions I have found. With that being said, I'm modelling a bishop as part of one of my first projects. I'm doing this by using a screw modifier. I am getting weird shading using smooth shading. I tried both orders of the other modifiers, but they are both bad. Is there any way to fix this while still keeping the non destructive modifier based model? Thanks!

[image: subsurface and then boolean]
subsurface and then boolean
[image: boolean and then subsurface]

boolean and then subsurface

Comment: Auto-smooth should be able to clear this up by keeping the edges sharp.  Adjust the angle threshold until you get something you like.

Comment: If you think you have an uncommon problem it would be very helpful if you included your blend file so we can look at it.

Comment: @AllenSimpson thank  you so much, never knew that feature existed before!